# Livewire Pagination is not responding

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

Why there is so much problems with this pagination from livewire? i have been see many topics of this.. and srsly i don't get it.. what wrong im doing? https://i.imgur.com/PENGFjf.gifv <- problem

if i go manualy and i write "?page=2" in url adress it is working, but i don't have any actions inside, clicking in pagination buttons

```
| "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
| "laravel/jetstream": "^2.3",
| "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
| "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
| "livewire/livewire": "^2.5"
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ShopComponent extends Component
{
     use WithPagination;
  
    
    public function render()
    {    
        return view('livewire.shop-component', ['products' => Product::paginate(9)])->layout('layouts.base');
    }

    public function paginationView()
    {
        return 'livewire.custom-pagination';
    }
}
```

Custom  pagination is copy from vendor - bootstrap pagination

```
    <div>
        @if ($paginator->hasPages())
        <nav class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <ul class="pagination mt-30 mb-30">
                {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                        <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <button type="button" dusk="previousPage" class="page-link" wire:click="previousPage" wire:loading.attr="disabled" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</button>
                    </li>
                @endif

                {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
                @foreach ($elements as $element)
                    {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                    @if (is_string($element))
                        <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span class="page-link">{{ $element }}</span></li>
                    @endif

                    {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                    @if (is_array($element))
                        @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                            @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                                <li class="page-item active" wire:key="paginator-page-{{ $page }}" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">{{ $page }}</span></li>
                            @else
                                <li class="page-item" wire:key="paginator-page-{{ $page }}"><button type="button" class="page-link" wire:click="gotoPage({{ $page }})">{{ $page }}</button></li>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                @endforeach

                {{-- Next Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <button type="button" dusk="nextPage" class="page-link" wire:click="nextPage" wire:loading.attr="disabled" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</button>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                        <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </nav>
    @endif
        
</div>
```

shop-component
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQMs0.png

```
<div>
 @foreach ($products as $product)
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-30">
                        <div class="card product-card">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="product-thumbnail position-relative">
                              <span class="badge badge-danger top-right">New</span>
                              <a href="single-product.html">
                                <img class="first-img" src="{{ asset('assets/img/product/1.png') }}" alt="thumbnail" />
                              </a>
                              <!-- product links -->
                              <ul class="actions d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <li>
                                  <a class="action" href="wishlist.html">
                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="add to wishlist" class="icon-heart">
                                    </span>
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                  <a class="action" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#compare">
                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add to compare" class="icon-shuffle"></span>
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                  <a class="action" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-view" >
                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Quick view" class="icon-magnifier"></span>
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                              </ul>

                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc py-0 px-0">
                              <h3 class="title">
                                <a href="shop-grid-4-column.html">{{ $product->name }}</a>
                              </h3>
                              <div class="star-rating">
                                <span class="ion-ios-star"></span>
                                <span class="ion-ios-star"></span>
                                <span class="ion-ios-star"></span>
                                <span class="ion-ios-star"></span>
                                <span class="ion-ios-star de-selected"></span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" >
                                <span class="product-price">{{ $product->regular_price }}</span>
                                <button class="pro-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-to-cart"  >
                                  <i class="icon-basket"></i>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
@endforeach
                
{{-- Paginacja produktów --}}
{{ $products->links() }}      
</div>
```

Comment: 1) It's generaly preferable to wrap the `for loop` in a div. 2) Does your products `div`' are using a key (e.g.) `wire:key="product_{{ $product->id }}"` https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting

Comment: I dont use any $loop

Comment: I mean't `foreach`, btw, `$loop` is available in both. It'a a [magic variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) But you don't need to use it. In fact, I wouldn't recommand it for this, as the order of your products may change. The `wire:key` is the equivalent of a unique identifier that helps Livewire trakcing changes when HTML content change. Please try it and see if it helps

Comment: What you exactly mean? Because i'm still learning. Look at this https://i.imgur.com/ol9WZ1t.png

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
php artisan livewire:publish --assets
```

second , make sure to add this lines in the main template.

```
<head>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    {{ $slot }}
 
    @livewireScripts
</body>
```